# Is it possible to remove the chapter title but keep it in the table of contents

Tags: chapters, titles

I am writing a report and am trying to save space due to a page limit and so want to remove the chapter title from 2 chapters in my report but keep it in the table of contents (as this'll provide a few more lines in these chapters). Ie, I still want to keep 'Chapter X', just not have the title ie 'Methods' below at the start of each chapter. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Use the optional argument to `\chapter`.

```
\chapter[put this in the ToC]{title text in the document}
```

so

```
\chapter[Methods]{}
```